# Monitor log and send Alert mail using shell script in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, email

I created .sh file to grep specific words in log and will send a mail to particular emailID (Set Cronjob to run this script every 1hour). Its working as expected, But the Problem is if there is no error also I am getting Empty Mail.

Needs to get Mail, if we caught error and DBError file has content. Kindly please help me on this to resolve this issue.

```
    #!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e DBErrors ] ; then
      grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log > DBErrors
      mail -s "ALERT: sqlException" Jayaram.Ponnusamy@gmail.com < DBErrors
else
  comm -23 <(grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log) DBErrors | mail -s "ALERT: sqlException" Jayaram.Ponnusamy@gmail.com
  grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log > DBErrors
fi
```

Thanks
Jayaram

Comment: Do you mean you need an email sent in the `if` block or in the `else` one?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
dbErrors="/tmp/DBErrors"
if [ ! -e "$dbErrors" ]; then
        grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log > $dbErrors
        mailbody=$(grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log); [[ -n "$mailbody" ]] && mail -s "ALERT: sqlException" Jayaram.Ponnusamy@gmail.com
else 
        mailbody=$(comm -23 <(grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log| sort -n) <(sort -n "$dbErrors")); [[ -n "$mailbody" ]] && mail -s "ALERT: sqlException" Jayaram.Ponnusamy@gmail.com
        grep "sqlException" /opt/apps/cms/logs/cms-runtime.log > $dbErrors
fi
```

Comment: Sorry still getting empty mail

Comment: @JayaramPonnusamy : I updated ans. could you try this;

Comment: Hi Mustafa, Still getting the same "Empty Body Message"